# Can't change context in Javascript ?

Tags: javascript

*I'm breaking my head here.* I have this simple code :

```
function myFunc()
{
    this.a = "aaa";

    return {
        h: function ()
        {
                   alert(this.a);
        }
    }
}



var f = new myFunc();
console.log(f.h.apply(f)) //I'm expecting to see here : "aaa" but it says "undefined"
```

`f.h` look *exactly* like this :

```
 function ()
 {
      alert(this.a);
     }
```

And so , i'm trying to set context to `f` itself (*which contains the `a` prop*) via `apply`.

But it doesn't work.

What am I missing ?

*p.s. there are other alternatives. I know. but why my **specific** code doesn't work ?*

Comment: You're returning an object from "myFunc" but add the property `a` to the function "myFunc" itself rather than to this returned object. Do `console.log(f);` and you'll see that f does not have a property `a`.

Comment: @Niko I guess  I was trying to get the benefit from both worlds. Object and to return closure ( for not exsposing all fields)....I guess it doesnt work.

Comment: why do you want to return an object from the constructor

Comment: @ArunPJohny read my prev comment. :) thanks.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Make `a` a local variable (i.e., `var a = "aaa";`) if you'd like to have private members.

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/44ZKZ/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`f` does not contain a, since you return an arbitrary object that 'overwrites' the default object that would otherwise have been returned, and that would have contained a.

If you used

```
function myFunc() {
  return {
    a:"aaa",
    h:function() { alert this.a; }
  }
}
```

then it would work!

If you want to use 'private' and 'public' variables then make it like this

```
function myFunc() {
  var a = "aaa";
  return {
    h:function() { alert a; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use closure, create `a` as a local variable. This will make `a` as a private property which outside world will not be able to access directly

```
function myFunc(){
    var a = "aaa";

    return {
        h: function ()   {
            alert(a);
        }
    }
}

var f = new myFunc();
console.log(f.h(f))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/44ZKZ/2/)

Comment: what about this situation where the function is outside ? http://jsbin.com/ofucac/4/edit

Comment: it will not work because `a` is not available outside `myFunc`, it is accessible via only closure

Comment: in that case you need a instance variable as mentioned in the accepted answer, then you can pass `this` to `s` and in `s` you can access `a` via the `param.a`

Answer (score 2):

When you are returning an object from the function you are getting that object instead of the object that was created by the ˋnewˋ keyword. The object where you put the ˋaˋ property doesn't exit any more.

Put the method in the object that is created instead of creating a different object:

```
function myFunc() {
  this.a = "aaa";

  this.h = function () {
    alert(this.a);
  }
}
```

Now the object contains the property, so you don't need to use apply to get the right context:

```
var f = new myFunc();
console.log(f.h())
```

Answer (score 1):

First, keep track of how you're returning and printing items. You're attempting to use both `alert` and `console.log` for this job when you should be only using one. In addition, you're attempting to `console.log` the return value of a function that doesn't return anything. For my example below, I chose to use `console.log` and kept the function returning nothing. Below, I fixed this first problem:

```
function myFunc() {
    this.a = "aaa";
    return {h: function () {console.log(this.a);}}
}

var f = new myFunc();
f.h.apply(f);
```

Now onto the real problem. `this.a` returns `undefined` because `this` is bound to different two different things (first an instance of `myFunc`, and then `f`) the two times you use it in your code. You can use `console.log(this)` to verify this.

To solve this problem, bind a variable (let's call it `self`) to `this` so that you can reference it later. In JavaScript, inner functions have access to variables bound in outer functions. (This is called [*closure*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102).) This allows us to use `self` in the following way:

```
function myFunc() {
    var self = this;
    this.a = "aaa";
    return {h: function() {console.log(self.a);}}
}

var f = new myFunc();
// f.h.apply(f); // replaced by next line; see first comment
f.h();
```

This prints the line `aaa` to the console.

Comment: Thanks. p.s.-  like my answer to bangerang , the `apply` in your sample is redundant. cause you're keeping the context. and so-- your code can be changed to `f.h()` - without the `apply`

Comment: Ooh, didn't see the other answers until after I posted. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You are losing scope with the closure, try this:

```
function myFunc()
{
    this.a = "aaa";
    that = this;
    return {
        h: function ()
        {
                   alert(that.a);
        }
    }
}



var f = new myFunc();
console.log(f.h.apply(f))
```

Comment: in your solution I can do only `console.log(f.h())` we dont need apply here

Comment: what are you talking about? console.log(f.h.apply(f)) works here as well

Comment: correct. but it is **redundant**  - since you keep the `this` ref.(`that`)